# Spoon Studio crashes or please suggest another all-to-one-exe-packer. :)

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I have downloaded trial of Spoon Studio, yet it crashes on startup.

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing it? Their support keeps silent.

Or maybe you could suggest another obfuscator(?), i.e. a tool or a way to pack all the needed *.DLLs and other stuff into one .exe file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't do obfuscation, but [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) will merge multiple assemblies for you.

Alternatively, you could always contact the tech support for Spoon Studio. (Can't say I've ever heard of it before.)

Answer (score 2):

I am biased since Dotfuscator helps pay my mortgage but it will obfuscate your assemblies as well as merge them all into a single file (or multiple files if you want).  The only caveat is that you cannot (yet) merge WPF assemblies as we don't fix up the locations of resources defined in pack URI's.  This same issue is also present in ILMerge and other packaging utilities.

You can get a [free two week trial](http://preemptive.com/landing/eval-request) to ensure it works for you before you buy, and our support guys are outstanding.